# Reading complex matlab arrays in Python with h5py

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, h5py

Hi I have a mat file which is comprised of complex array C and real arrays A,B . When I do the following

```
with h5py.File('test.mat','r') as file:
    A_ = np.array(file['A'])
    B_ = np.array(file['B'])   
    C_ = np.array(file['C'])
```

I am able to access A_ and B_ without a problem but I can't access to imaginary part of C_ .

```
np.imag(C_)
C_.imag
```

These don't work, also type of C_ is void and it cannot be casted to complex. I get the following error

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype([('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')]) to dtype('complex128') according to the rule 'unsafe'

Comment: It looks like the array `C_` is a recarray. You reference the real and imaginary fields separately -- like this: `C_['real']` `C_['imag']`. To get the complex value of the first entry, use: `cplx_val = np.img( C_['real'][0] + C_['imag'][0]*i] )`

Comment: Great! Probably should have posted as an answer. LOL :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's expand on my comment to complete the task of creating an array of complex numbers (from a recarray of real and imaginary components).

Lines 1 creates array `C_` to mimic the extracted Matlab array, and lines 4-5 populates it with values.
Line 7 creates array `cplx` from array `C_` array referencing fields `'rea'` and `'imag'`. Note how `*1j` is used to define the imaginary part when the term is a variable (e.g., not a constant).

```
In [1]: C_ = np.recarray((10,),dtype=[('real','<f8'), ('imag','<f8')] )
In [2]: C_.dtype
Out[2]: dtype((numpy.record, [('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')]))
In [3]: C_.shape
Out[3]: (10,)

In [4]: C_[:]['real'] = [i for i in range(10,110,10)]
In [5]: C_[:]['imag'] = [i for i in range(1,11)]
In [6]: C_
Out[6]: 
rec.array([( 10.,  1.), ( 20.,  2.), ( 30.,  3.), ( 40.,  4.),
           ( 50.,  5.), ( 60.,  6.), ( 70.,  7.), ( 80.,  8.),
           ( 90.,  9.), (100., 10.)],
          dtype=[('real', '<f8'), ('imag', '<f8')])

In [7]: cplx = C_['real'] + C_['imag']*1j
In [8]: cplx
Out[8]: 
array([ 10. +1.j,  20. +2.j,  30. +3.j,  40. +4.j,  50. +5.j,  60. +6.j,
        70. +7.j,  80. +8.j,  90. +9.j, 100.+10.j])
In [9]: cplx.dtype
Out[9]: dtype('complex128')
```